# how to find the grant permission for objects from user schema

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

I have a situation like this. I have schema which has high level user '`db1owner`' and low level user '`db1user`'.

'`db1owner`' has grant some permissions to view, table, and other schema objects for '`db1user`'.

Now I want to know the list of objects which all grant by '`db1owner`' with permission details.

How can find it?

Any help indeed!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ALL_TAB_PRIVS data dictionary table.

Something like....

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE  GRANTOR = 'db1owner'
AND    GRANTEE = 'db1user'
```

Description of ALL_TAB_PRIVS:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2099.htm